# how to get input parameters of any method of a class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, methods, parameters

Let's say I have a class with 10 methods, each method has different parameters.

I want to log input parameters of all methods of said class without having to do edit each method to insert that logging code. Is there away to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wrap it with decorator with magic `__call` http://ideone.com/n9ZUD

```
class TargetClass
{
    public function A($a, $b) {}
    public function B($c, $d) {}
    public function C($e, $f) {}
}

class LoggingDecorator
{
    private $_target;

    public function __construct($target)
    {
        $this->_target = $target;
    }

    public function __call($name, $params)
    {
        $this->_log($name, $params);

        return call_user_func_array(array($this->_target, $name), $params);
    }

    private function _log($name, $params)
    {
        echo $name . ' has been called with params: ' . implode(', ', $params) . '<br>';
    }
}

$target = new TargetClass();
$logger = new LoggingDecorator($target);

$logger->A(1, 2);
$logger->A(3, 4);
```

The only disadvantage of this approach is that you will lose the type of the decorated class, e.g. you won't be able to satisfy type hints with it. If that is a concern, distill the interface of TargetClass and implement it in the LoggingDecorator.

Comment: @Gordon: I liked your separated logger, virtual +1 to the deleted answer ;-)

Comment: @zerks thanks. I was tempted to edit your code to have it separate, too ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I decided to modify the class's method and add __call().

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, no.

You could rename all your methods to have an underscore suffix, e.g.:

```
myFunction() -> _myFunction()
```

Then, write add the magic [`__call()`](http://sg.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) method to intercept calls to the previous (unprefixed) methods. Then you would log the request and pass on all arguments to the original method.

It's kind of ugly and still requires a change to all your method names.

Comment: Underscores are recommended to not be used since 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I might be over simplifying this - but you can retrieve all the arguments of a function using

```
func_get_args();
```

> Returns an array comprising a function's argument list
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

```
<?php
  function foo() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    var_export($args);
  }
  foo('arg1', 'arg1');
?>
```

That would output something like this -

```
array (
  0 => 'arg1',
  1 => 'arg2',
)
```

---

There are a few notes to be added here - you should read the documentation link I provided - one "limitation" is -

> **Note:**
>   This function returns a copy of the passed arguments only, and does not account for default (non-passed) arguments.